# Randomly sample a n-vector from the orthogonal complement of a matrix $A \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Let $A \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m}$ be a matrix of $m$ n-vectors.  Is there a way to randomly sample (assume uniform distribution) a vector from the orthogonal complement of A without computing the nullspace or kernel of $A$.

Note that the sampling is always possible if the kernel $Z$ is known. We can always uniformly sample $x$ as $x= Zc$ where Z is the nullspace of $A$ and $c$ is a uniformly sampled vector.

But I am specifically interested in computing $x$ directly from $A$ when $Z$ is not known or cannot be computed.

Comment: Wouldn't orthogonal projection of a random vector $v$ onto the kernel of $A$ via $\text{proj}_{\text{ker}(A)}(v) = (I - A^+ A) v$ work? We only need pseudo-inverse computation, which may be difficult but that's the best thing I can think of.

Comment: Maybe clarify what ‘uniformly’ means to you. I doubt $x$ given by $x = Zc$ will have a uniform distribution.